# How to calculate RAM usage in android device?

Tags: android

I am trying to calculate the Ram usage when I run my application. I saw a few posts on stackoverflow but cldnt quite understand how they go about it. 
Can anyone help me in finding the memory(RAM) usage in my device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate available memory and if running on API level bigger than 16 you can get the total memory. From there you can have the memory usage.
I am using the following method in my app. It returns the memory available in MBs.

```
private void showAvailableMemory(){
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    Log.i(TAG, "Available memory = " + availableMegs + " MB");
}
```

If you are running on API level > 16, you can use [MemoryInfo.totalMem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html#totalMem) to get the device memory.

Comment: Why do we divide it by 1048576L ?

Comment: oh ok got it..1024*1024 (MB)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer:

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

But basically, you should check the USS value:

```
adb shell procrank -u
```

Example:

```
  PID      Vss      Rss      Pss      Uss  cmdline
  492   73540K   73336K   51256K   49780K  system_server
  676   53712K   53008K   31831K   30696K  com.android.systemui
13918   46408K   46376K   21050K   19504K  com.facebook.katana
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to calculate..

```
ActivityManager activityManager = = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
```

Get the available memory from memoryInfo.

Also, to measure Use this tool , which will show you the memory usage of your app
 http://www.littleeye.co/

Comment: I want to calculate it. Not just mesure it with a tool

Comment: Modified the answer. Pls check